# ASP.NET - Detech the Label Text To Pass Variable

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET

What I try to do is capture the unique ID (ProposedID) in the lblProposedID field, and pass it to another page.

Lable in the GridView

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" 
    SortExpression="ID" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblProposedID" runat="server" 
        Text='<%#Eval("ProposedID") %>'>
    </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind

```
private void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    String rColor;
    System.Drawing.ColorConverter colConvert = new ColorConverter();

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int RowNum = e.Row.RowIndex;
        if (RowNum % 2 == 1)
        {
            rColor = "#FFFFFF";
            //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#DDDDDD'");
        }
        else
        {
            rColor = "#F5F5F5";
            //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='" ++ "'");
        }

        e.Row.BackColor = (System.Drawing.Color)colConvert.ConvertFromString(rColor);
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='" + rColor + "'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#00FFFF'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('popup.aspx?ProposedID=" + (Label)  e.Row.FindControl("lblProposedID") + 
        "','cal','width=600,height=300,left=270,top=180')"); 
        //e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

This is the line when I couldn't get it to work.

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('popup.aspx?textbox={0}" + (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProposedID") + 
"','cal','width=600,height=300,left=270,top=180')");
```

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OnRowDataBound` instead. The text was always null in that event but when I changed it to RowDataBound, it picked the ID

**Add RowDataBound event**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowCreated">
```

**CodeBehind**

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        String rColor;

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int RowNum = e.Row.RowIndex;
            if (RowNum % 2 == 1)
            {
                rColor = "#FFFFFF";
                //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#DDDDDD'");
            }
            else
            {
                rColor = "#F5F5F5";
                //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='" ++ "'");
            }

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='" + rColor + "'");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#00FFFF'");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('popup.aspx?ProposedID=" + ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProposedID")).Text +
            "','cal','width=600,height=300,left=270,top=180')");
            //e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change a part of how you make the js line to this:

`((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProposedID")).Text`

That will get the actual text from the label.

Comment: I tried that, but it just passing a nothing. I even tried this "((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProposedID")).Text.ToString()", no luck.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!